How to Ignore "Unresolved Reference" Error for a Specific Variable in PyCharm?
In my project, I have a variable gl that is globally recognized throughout the repository because I use a custom interpreter to run the code. However, when working in PyCharm, the IDE does not recognize this variable, resulting in numerous "Unresolved reference 'gl'" errors.
Is there a way to configure PyCharm to ignore the "Unresolved reference" error for this specific variable across the entire project?
I know I can ignore this error for a specific file by adding the variable gl with the relative path (e.g., Setup.tools) to the ignore references in Inspections, but I couldn't find a way to apply this setting across the entire repository at once.


The answer is simple - just add gl without the prefix Setup.tools
